# Component is mounted but I can't call this.setState(...) or this.forceUpdate(...);

Tags: reactjs, mobile, react-native

I am using [scrollable tab view](https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view) and facebook official flux solution. There are cases when a scene remains inactive (is not current selected tab) and receive a event from the store that need to update the scene, but I have this error :
`Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.`

I've double checked, and `componentWillUnmount()` is not being called .. but I receive this warning and I can't more update the state of component.

Here I have some sample code of the component that has this problem being in the unselected tab:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isFavorite: this.isCurrentPostFavorite,
      isMounted: false,
      value: 0,
    };

    this.updateStateForFavoriteModification = this.updateStateForFavoriteModification.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isMounted: true});
    console.log('Article Scene did mount for article: '.toUpperCase() + this.props.sceneInfo.article.name);
    HotelStore.bind(HotelEvent.didModifiedFavorite, this.updateStateForFavoriteModification.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({isMounted: false});
    console.log('Article Scene will unmount for article: '.toUpperCase() + this.props.sceneInfo.article.name);
    HotelStore.unbind(HotelEvent.didModifiedFavorite, this.updateStateForFavoriteModification);
  }

  changeFavoriteStatus() {
    if (this.state.isFavorite) {
      sendAction(HotelAction.removeFavorite, this.props.sceneInfo.article);
    }
    else {
      sendAction(HotelAction.addFavorite, this.props.sceneInfo.article);
    }
  }

  updateStateForFavoriteModification() {
    console.log('Update: '.toUpperCase() + this.props.sceneInfo.article.name);
    console.log('isMounted: '.toUpperCase() + this.state.isMounted);

    //
    //
    // Here I Get the error
    this.setState({isFavorite: this.isCurrentPostFavorite});
  }

  get isCurrentPostFavorite() {
    let matchNumber = HotelStore.favoritesPosts.filter((el: Post) => {
      return el.translationId === this.props.sceneInfo.article.translationId;
    }).length;
    let isFavorite = matchNumber > 0;
    console.log(isFavorite);
    return isFavorite;
  }
```

As result component did mount log `console.log('Article Scene will unmount for article: '.toUpperCase() + this.props.sceneInfo.article.name);` is never shown before updating state, also before `this.setState(...)` the bool `isMounted` is always `true` in the log.

**EDIT**: I know about `isMounted` and that's an antipatern, I've used this only to inspect in logs if the component is mounted or not, If I remove `isMounted` logic the error still persist.

Comment: Please provide relevant code samples

Comment: @mbernardeau done

Comment: Which, of all `setState`, is triggering that error/warning in the console?

Comment: the one from `updateStateForFavoriteModification()` function, that's called as response from the store event.

Comment: As César points out, you should get rid of the isMounted state altogether and see if your problem persists and/or changes. Unnecessary state means more re-renders, and more chances for unintended component behaviour. Also, is it the `updateStateForFavoriteModification()` callback in componentDidMount or componentWilUnmount that is being called when that warning is generated?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't want to check if your component is mounted or not, [it's an antipattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html).

I guess the warning appears because you are using setState in componentWillUnmount. I think that the problem with this is that **setState is asynchronous**, so the state might not be changed inmediately when you call the function.. In this case, it might try to change the state when the component is already unmounted.

Comment: I know about `isMounted` and that's an antipatern, I've used this only to inspect in logs if the component is mounted or not, If I remove `isMounted` logic the error still persist.